# 500 error when creating action in rule ''Create linked drupal user account''

Tags: drupal, user-account, drupal-rules

I am trying to create a rule based on the blog post here: https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-for-single-or-multiple-contacts-via-civi-imports-and

I'm recreating the rule manually but when I try to create the action 'Create linked drupal user account' I get this error, does anyone know why?

> 2016/11/07 15:09:43 [error] 28899#28899: *113846 FastCGI sent in
>   stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in
>   /var/www/xxxxxx/includes/form.inc on line 2760" while reading response
>   header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request:
>   "POST /system/ajax HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com",
>   referrer:
>   "https://example.com/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/rules_entity_tag_create_drupal_user/add/1/action"

Comment: Any reason you didn't try just with importing the Rule? Did you grab CiviCRM Entity from https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity

Comment: Think we tried that but it didn't work. This did however:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got this working using this rule:

```
{ "rules_friends_tag_account_create" : {
"LABEL" : "Self Create User Account and login",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "CiviCRM", "CiviCRM User" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "civicrm" ],
"ON" : { "civicrm_entity_tag_create" : [] },
"IF" : [ { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "civicrm-entity-tag:tag-id" ], "value" : "163" } }
],
"DO" : [ { "civicrm_entity_action_load_create_user" : {
"USING" : {
"civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm-entity-tag:entity-id-contact" ],
"is_active" : "1",
"notify" : "1" 
},
"PROVIDE" : { "civicrm_user" : { "civicrm_user" : "Created or Loaded Drupal User" } }
}
}
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's been some updated to the Create or Load Drupal User action in CiviCRM Entity beta6, that has improved handling of user creation. Grab beta6 or higher to get the improvement.

If there are continued problems, make a support request / bug issue in the module issue queue on D.O and we'll figure it out